# Trying to query soap:Body elements using xpath

Tags: php, soap, xpath, domdocument, xml-namespaces

This is my SOAP XML document:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2012 15:42:41 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 424

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <LoginResponse xmlns="http://localhost/SPFService/">
        <LoginResult>
          <Reply xmlns="">
            <SessionID>cdfbe607-59b1-4912-ae54-2190f1b7c7dd
            </SessionID>
          </Reply>
        </LoginResult>
      </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Now I need to access the TextNode value of the SessionID element. I've created an xpath using:

```
$this->dom->loadXML($response);
$this->xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
```

, where $response is a string containing the above xml.

The problem is I can only query `"/soap:Envelope"` and `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body"`. If I try to query `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/LoginResponse"` I get an empty `DOMNodeList`. How do I debug this mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out what I was doing wrong.

Since the tag LoginResponse has an "xmlns" attribute, I need to register the attribute namespace value with a prefix (I used "x") on the client. This is done like so:

```
$this->xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
$this->xpath->registerNamespace('x', "http://localhost/SPFService/");
```

, where "http://localhost/SPFService/" is the attribute "xmlns" value for the LoginResponse tag. Then I can use xpathQuery to find, ie., "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/x:LoginResponse". Note that I prefix "LoginResponse" with "x:".